# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '3'

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, gensim

I am creating a chatbot. So, i need word2vec file in binary format.
When i am loading bin file then i am getting this type of error.

```
import gensim

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/surya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 975, in load
return super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/surya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 629, in load
model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/surya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 278, in load
return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
File "/home/surya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 395, in load
obj = unpickle(fname)
File "/home/surya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1302, in unpickle
return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')_pickle.

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '3'.
```

Comment: take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659985/error-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-0-invalid-start-byte/48131463#48131463

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it is a binary file you need to mention it like this:

```
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec
model = word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```